# How can I use hardware VPN connections from the cloud?

Tags: networking, vpn, cloud, azure

We currently host our servers in a typical hosting environment. We connect to several third parties via VPN connections. Each third party stipulates what VPN devices we can use to connect to their network. In each case they require a hardware VPN device is used, and in one case the third party demands we use their hardware VPN device in our network.

We are now evaluating moving our services and web applications into the cloud (Azure in this case). However after looking into the VPN options, Azure and I guess most cloud environments would not be able to satisfy our requirements as they do not have the capability to host hardware VPN devices.

If we move to a cloud hosting environment, what are the options available to be able to connect to these third party VPNs? I presume we would need to host the VPN device(s) in a traditional hosting environment, but how would we route through it from the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

That is a "simple" routing issue. Just make sure the right routes are in place to get your stuff routed through the devices you need. E.g. Cloud -> Hosting -> VPN -> Partner.